# Runtime error when compiling this piece of code can anyone help me

Tags: c++

An operation on the array is defined to be: replace the k-th smallest integer in the array with any integer you want.

Output the minimum number of operations you must perform on the array (possibly 0 operations) to make the p-th smallest element of the array equal to X. If it is impossible to do so output −1.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#define mod 1000000007
using namespace std;

int
findIndex (int a[], int n, int x, int p)
{
  
int min = 100000000, minp;
  
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    
if (a[i] == x)
      {
    
if (abs (p - i) < min)
      {
        
min = abs (p - i);
        
minp = i;
      
}
      
}
  
return minp;

}


void
subMain ()
{
  
int N, X, p, k;
  
cin >> N >> X >> p >> k;
  
int a[N];
  
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    
cin >> a[i];
  
sort (a, a + N);
  
int index = findIndex (a, N, X, p);
  
int count = 0;
  
if (a[index] != X)
    {
      
a[k - 1] = X;
      
sort (a, a + N);
      
count++;
    
}
  
if (a[p - 1] == X)
    {
      
cout << 0 + count;
      
return;
    
}
  
if (p < k && a[p - 1] < X)
    {
      
cout << -1;
      
return;
    
}
  
if (p > k && a[p - 1] > X)
    {
      
cout << -1;
      
return;
    
}
  
index = findIndex (a, N, X, p) + 1;
  
cout << abs (p - index) + count;

}


int
main ()
{
  
ios_base::sync_with_stdio (false);
  
cin.tie (NULL);
  
int t = 1;
  
cin >> t;
  
while (t--)
    {
      
subMain ();
      
cout << "\n";
    
}
  
return 0;

}
```

Comment: I suggest you should format your code properly with indents.

Comment: How does one get a run-time error while compiling?  Does the code compile?  Is the error after compilation, during run-time?